# How to remove spacing inserted due to anchors when placing images using `tikzpicture`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to create a frame with an image being stretched across the entire height of a page with some comments posts to the left.

[image]

However, as you see in the picture, a small gap exists between the image and the right edge of the frame. What causes this gap to appear? How to get rid of it such that the image is entirely flushed to the right edge? I believe it could be because of how `tikz` handles anchors

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\removeNavigation}{\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan}

\begin{document}

{\removeNavigation
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.4\paperwidth}}
        
        \blindlist{itemize}
        
    \end{adjustbox}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=east] at (current page.east)
        {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{frame}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try  \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing is caused by the initially non-zero `inner sep` (0.3333em) of node. Setting `inner sep=0pt` removes that spacing.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\removeNavigation}{\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan}

\begin{document}

{\removeNavigation
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={0.4\paperwidth}}
        \blindlist{itemize}
    \end{adjustbox}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.east)
        {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]